# Capturing emoticons

Tags: julia

Does anyone know if there is a package in Julia that allows capturing a wide range of emoticons/emojis in text? I am trying to do sentiment analysis for a disaster-related Twitter dataset. There is a lot of emoticons with a prayer symbol as well as the horse symbol and others (It's related to the Taal disaster where a lot of animals died).
Just want to know if there is a way to capture a wide variety of emojis.

Comment: there is a discussion about detecting emojis [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/38458)